# Is this extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a = \sqrt{\sqrt2 + \sqrt3}$  Is $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I thought the answer was no because the minimum polynomial of $a$ is $x^8 -10x^4 + 1$ so $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$ and I read a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316588/when-is-the-extension-bbbq-sqrt-sqrt5-a-bbbq-normal) where they say that is a normal extension iff the order of the Galois group is 4, but wouldn't this mean the order of the Galois group is 8?  Also, wouldn't an extension by $a$ not include anything imaginary and therefore only half of the other roots.
I would almost definitely conclude that this extension is not normal, but part b of the question is to describe the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q})$ up to isomorphism, which would mean that the extension would have to be normal

Comment: How can a rational extension be normal **only** if its degree is four? That is blatantly false.

Comment: @DonAntonio  I think they just meant by roots of this form, but I think my argument about imaginary roots still stands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal closure of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\sqrt2+\sqrt3})$ contains a square
root $\alpha$ of $\sqrt2-\sqrt3$. As $\alpha^2<0$, $\alpha\notin\Bbb R$.
As $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\sqrt2+\sqrt3})\subseteq\Bbb R$, then $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\sqrt2+\sqrt3})$ is not a normal extension of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: then how can I do part b?  If the extension isn't normal, its not Galois?

Comment: Then how about finding the Galois group of the normal closure? @user558377

Comment: So I should find the splitting field $E$ of $f = x^8 -10x^4 +1$ and then find $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})?$  Is that still the same question?

Comment: So I know that the roots of $f= x^8 -10x^4 + 1$ are $\pm \sqrt{\pm \sqrt{5 \pm 2\sqrt6}}$  So would the normal closure be $\mathbb{Q}(a, i)$ or am I missing something that takes care of the root $\sqrt {\sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt6}}$?

Comment: There's a relation between the square root of $\sqrt3+\sqrt2$ and the square root of $\sqrt3-\sqrt2$. @user558377

Comment: In other words, would the normal closure be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}, \sqrt[4]{5 - 2\sqrt6}, i)$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}, i)$?

Comment: Sorry I think we were writing our comments at the same time.  So the answer is $E = \mathbb{Q}(a = \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}, i)$, which would mean $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}) = [E:\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(a, i): \mathbb{Q}(a)][\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}] = 2 \times 8 = 16$ so the Galois group is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_8$ of order 16?