# Proving that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}+\sqrt{q}},\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}-\sqrt{q}}):\mathbb{Q}]=8$.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Some days ago I posted a question in MSE in order to correct a solution to the problem of [Prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5}},\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5}}):\mathbb{Q}]=8$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086588/prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt4-sqrt5-sqrt4-sqrt5-mathbbq-8)

After posting this another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092833/prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5-mathbbq-8), I found a general argument for this type of extensions. I think that the ideas at the solution of *Bill Dubuque* in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f) could be used to solve the following problem:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct positive prime numbers such that $p+q$ is a perfect square. Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}+\sqrt{q}},\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}-\sqrt{q}}):\mathbb{Q}]=8.$

**My attempt of solution:**

Let $\alpha_1 = \sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}+\sqrt{q}}$ and $\alpha_2=\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}-\sqrt{q}}).$ Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$.

First observe that $$\alpha_1^2 = \sqrt{p+q}+\sqrt{q},$$ and $$\alpha_1 \alpha_2 = \sqrt{p}.$$

Let $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1^2,\alpha_1 \alpha_2)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q},\sqrt{p}).$ We have that $[\mathbb{L}:\mathbb{Q}]=4,$ hence $\mathbb{L}$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}),$ with basis $\{1,\sqrt{p}\}$. We will prove now that $\alpha_1 \not\in \mathbb{L}:$

Suppose that $\alpha_1 \in \mathbb{L}$ (this imply directly that $\alpha_2 \in \mathbb{L}$ too), then exists unique $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$ with $$\alpha_1 = a + b\sqrt{p}.$$ Hence, $$\sqrt{p+q}+\sqrt{q} = a^2 + p b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{p},$$ or equivalently: $$2ab\sqrt{p} = \sqrt{p+q}+\sqrt{q} - a^2 - p a^2.$$

Since the right member of the equality is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}),$ must be $a=0$ or $b=0$.

- If $a=0$ then $\alpha_1 = b\sqrt{p}=b\alpha_1 \alpha_2,$ hence $1=b\alpha_2$ and we conclude that $\alpha_2^{-1}=b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}).$
- If $b=0$ then $\alpha_1=a \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}).$

Both cases gets a contradiction since $\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}\pm\sqrt{q}}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}).$ If we suppose that $$\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}\pm\sqrt{q}}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}),$$ then exists unique $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $$\sqrt{\sqrt{p+q}\pm\sqrt{q}}=a+b\sqrt{q}.$$ Hence
$$\sqrt{p+q}\pm\sqrt{q} = a^2 + qb^2+2ab\sqrt{q},$$ and must be $ab=\pm1/2$ and $\sqrt{p+q} = a^2 + qb^2.$ Solving for $a$ we get that $a$ is a root of the polynomial $$4x^4-4\sqrt{p+q}x^2+q.$$ Hence $a$ have one of the following four values: $$\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{p+q}}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}},$$ but any of these values is a rational, if not, $$\bigg(\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{p+q}}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}}\bigg)^2=\frac{\sqrt{p+q}}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}.$$

With this we conclude the proof and get the original claim.

**End.**

The problem I posted some days ago is a special case with $p = 11$ and $q = 5$.

Is this approach correct? I'm interested in reading Galois-type solutions since I think they are more "beautiful". Which are the pair of distinct positive primes whose sum is a perfect square? I see the pairs $(11,5)$, $(23,2)$ and $(31,5)$ for example.

Thaks to everyone.

Comment: Notice that your last question is either (case p=2) equivalent to looking for primes of the form $n^2 -2$, see (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591333/primes-of-form-n2-2-where-n-is-odd-and-greater-than-1)  or (case pq odd) related to Goldbach's conjecture. In particular Goldbach predicts that for every $n\geq 3$ there are diferent primes $p,q$ such that $4n^2 = p +q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But this is again a quick application of the "kummerian argument" which I used in my answer to your question of a few days ago. Introduce $k=\mathbf Q(\sqrt p, \sqrt q)$, which is a biquadratic field because $pq$ cannot be a square in $\mathbf Q$ (by unique factorization in $\mathbf Z$)
. Consider then the extensions $k(\sqrt {\sqrt {p+q} \pm \sqrt q})$, where $p+q$ is a perfect square. Since $\sqrt {\sqrt {p+q}+\sqrt q} .\sqrt {\sqrt {p+q}-\sqrt q}=p$ is a square in $k^*$, the kummerian argument above $k$  shows that the extensions $k(\sqrt {\sqrt {p+q} \pm \sqrt q})$ are the same field, say $K$. Applying again Kummer over $\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)$ as base field, we see that $K=k=\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)(\sqrt p)$ iff $p(\sqrt {p+q}\pm \sqrt q)$ are squares in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)$; multiplying the two relations, we get that $p^3$ is a square in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)$ : impossible. Hence $[K:k]=2$ and $[K:\mathbf Q]=8$.

**Remark:**  In the kind of questions you are dealing with, the kummerian approach is more natural in the sense that it appeals only to the multiplicative structure of the fields involved, whereas a blunt direct approach mixes the multiplicative and additive structures.

Comment: Your remark is really useful, it gave me a good intuition for these extensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have $\sqrt {p+q}=n\in\Bbb N$, so i will use this $n$ below.

Let us consider the tower of fields:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
{} @. L=\Bbb Q\left(\ \sqrt {n\pm\sqrt q}\ \right)\\
@.    @AAA\\
{} @. K=\Bbb Q(\ \sqrt p, \sqrt q\ )\\
@.\nearrow @.\nwarrow\\
\Bbb Q(\sqrt p) @. {} @. \Bbb Q(\sqrt q )\\
@.\nwarrow @.\nearrow\\
{} @. \Bbb Q  @.{}
\end{CD}
Some remarks first:

- The extension $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt p,\sqrt q):\Bbb Q$ has degree four, else $\sqrt p$, $\sqrt q$ would differ by a rational factor, but $p\ne q$.
- The vertical arrow is an extension of fields.
  First $\sqrt q\in L$, since $n\pm\sqrt q\in L$.
  Also, because the product of the two numbers $\sqrt{n\pm\sqrt q}$
  is $\sqrt{n^2-q}=\sqrt{(p+q)-q}=\sqrt p$, we also have $\sqrt p\in L$.
- For short, $L=
  \Bbb Q\left(\ \sqrt {n+\sqrt q},\ \sqrt p,\ \sqrt q\ \right)
  =
  \Bbb Q\left(\ \sqrt {n-\sqrt q},\ \sqrt p,\ \sqrt q\ \right)
  =K(\sqrt {n+\sqrt q})
  =K(\sqrt {n-\sqrt q})
  $.

It remains to show that the extension $L:K$ has degree two.

If not, then we would have a linear relation over $\Bbb Q$ of the shape:
$$
\sqrt{n+\sqrt q}=A+B\sqrt q+\sqrt p(C+D\sqrt q)\in K\ .
$$
Apply now the Galois morphism $\sqrt p\to -\sqrt p$, $\sqrt q\to+\sqrt q$ of $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt p,\sqrt q)$, to get parallely
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \sqrt{n+\sqrt q} &=A+B\sqrt q+\sqrt p(C+D\sqrt q)\in K\ ,\\
\pm \sqrt{n+\sqrt q} &=A+B\sqrt q-\sqrt p(C+D\sqrt q)\in K\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(To be pedant and avoid any questions that i may put myself, i added that $\pm$ in the last relation, imposed by the minimal polynomial condition over $K$, the L.H.S being a root of $X^2 -n-\sqrt q\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt q)\ [X]$.)

The representation is unique, so we have either
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{n+\sqrt q} &=A+B\sqrt q\ ,\text{ or}\\
\sqrt{n+\sqrt q} &=\sqrt p(C+D\sqrt q)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We use now the other Galois morphism, $\sqrt p\to \sqrt p$, $\sqrt q\to-\sqrt q$, getting either 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pm\sqrt{n-\sqrt q} &=A-B\sqrt q\ ,\text{ or}\\
\pm\sqrt{n-\sqrt q} &=\sqrt p(C-D\sqrt q)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We multiply, so $\pm \sqrt{n+\sqrt q} \cdot \sqrt{n-\sqrt q}=\pm \sqrt{n^2-q}=\pm\sqrt p$ is either $A^2-qB^2\in\Bbb Q$ or $p(C^2-qD^2)\in \Bbb Q$, thus a contradiction.

The linear relation cannot hold. So the degree of the vertial field extension is two.

$\square$

Comment: I'm bothered by your  Q-linear relation, which involves only $\sqrt p$ and $\sqrt q$, whereas a basis of K/Q is {$1, \sqrt p, \sqrt q, \sqrt {pq}$}.

Comment: yes, thanks, a good point! have to rearrange things!