# Determine the Galois group (polynomial)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f(x)=x^4-6x^2+4 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $L$ a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

How to determine the Galois group?

My idea was:

$x^4-6x^2+4=(x^2)^2-6x^2+4$

So $x^2 \in \lbrace \frac{6}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{6}{2})^2-4} \rbrace = \lbrace 3+\sqrt{5},3-\sqrt{5} \rbrace$

Then $x \in \lbrace \sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}, \sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}} \rbrace$

These are two roots of the polynomial. Now I'm not sure what to do next. I thought about finding the other two roots, but I don't know how.

How to continue? Or is there a better method to find the Galois group here?

Comment: If you know $x^2 = a$, then $x = \pm \sqrt{a}$ is a complete set of solutions.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649466/11619) answer your question?