# Existence of solutions in $\mathbb{C}(t)$ to a system of algebraic equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, galois-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484653/an-exercise-in-galois-theory-dealing-with-function-fields/4484665#4484665) about finding the Galois group of the polynomial $p(x) = x^4+2utx^2+ t$ over the field $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is raised the question of whether $\sqrt t$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}(t)[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $p$ in an algebraic extension.

It turns out that answering that question is equivalent to deciding whether the system of algebraic equations

$$\begin{cases}
p_{0}^{2} - 2p_{1} p_{3} t - p_{2}^{2} t + 2 p_{3}^{2} t^{2} u - t &= 0\\
p_{0} p_{1} - p_{2} p_{3} t &= 0\\
2p_{0} p_{2} + p_{1}^{2} - 4 p_{1} p_{3} t u - 2 p_{2}^{2} t u + 4 p_{3}^{2} t^{2} u^{2} - p_{3}^{2} t &= 0\\
p_{0} p_{3} + p_{1} p_{2} - 2 p_{2} p_{3} t u &= 0
\end{cases}$$

have a solution in variables $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_2 \in \mathbb{C}(t)$.

I tried a bit to manipulate those equations to find a contradiction, mainly regarding the degrees of the polynomials that can be used to write the $p_i$. With no success so far.

Hence my questions:

1. What are the ways to tackle such a problem?
2. Is there some programming package that can be used regarding the existence of solutions to a system of algebraic equations?

Comment: Gröbner bases are used to solve systems of polynomial equations.