# Degree of $F(\alpha + \beta)$ over $F$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I asked a [similar auxiliary question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834672/degree-of-f-alpha-beta-over-f-alpha-beta) but have since realized it was erroneous. The setup is that I have an irreducible separable polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ of degree $n$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ distinct roots. I want to show that $[F(\alpha + \beta):F] \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. (This problem comes from a past qualifying exam).

I've already shown that $[F(\alpha, \beta):F] \leq n(n-1)$. My thought was that we can write
$$ [F(\alpha + \beta): F] = \frac{[F(\alpha, \beta): F]}{[F(\alpha, \beta): F(\alpha + \beta)]} \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{[F(\alpha, \beta): F(\alpha + \beta)]}$$
and if we can show that $[F(\alpha, \beta): F(\alpha + \beta)] \geq 2$, then we would be done. My impression from the answers in the auxiliary question I linked is that this latter inequality is not true in general. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something here, or there's a missing assumption in the problem as stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $F$-conjugates of $\alpha+\beta$ must lie among all the sums of two different roots of $f(x)$.  And we know $\alpha+\beta$ is separable over $F$ since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are, so $[F(\alpha+\beta):F]$ is bounded above by the number of *distinct* sums of two different roots of $f(x)$. At most how many such sums are there?