# Galois group of $X^4 + 2X^2+4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Find the Galois group of $f(X) = X^4 + 2X^2+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Finding the roots of this polynomial, I got $$X^2 = \frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4-16}}{2} = -1 \pm \sqrt{3}i$$ so the roots are $\alpha_1 = \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{3}i}, \alpha_2 =\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{3}}i, \alpha_3 =  -\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{3}i}$ and  $ \alpha_4 -\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{3}}i$.  Now $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$, and since $$\alpha_1 \alpha_2  = \sqrt{(-1 + \sqrt{3}i)(-1-\sqrt{3}i)} = \sqrt{1+3} = 2$$ we see that $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_2)$.  It's not difficult to see that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$, so the Galois group of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is is either $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

My guess is that this Galois group is cyclic, since I think that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$ (a cyclotomic extension by a cubic root of unity) is the only intermediate subfield of $L/\mathbb{Q}$.  How can I know for sure?

Comment: The question has no sense ! It should be "find the Galois group $Gal(E/\Bbb Q)$ where $E$ is the splitting field of $f(X)\in\Bbb Q[X]$"

Comment: The Galois group of a polynomial is a well-defined notion, which is exactly the one that you suggest by the way. I am not expert in notation but it seems that Galois theory was made first for polynomials and then for field extensions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory

Comment: @idm That's the definition of "Galois group of $f(X)$"

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204709

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also write the solutions in the following way: 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\pm \sqrt{2}\pm \sqrt{6}i\right)$$
and then find that $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}i]$. The Galois group is then $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.

One generator corresponds to the conjugation $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ and the second is $\alpha\mapsto -\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is one of your roots; this is an automorphism since $L=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and because $-\alpha$ is also a root.

Comment: Could you explain the first step please? About how to write the roots in this new form?

Comment: Does this work in more generality? I am trying to do a similar trick for $\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: @Sigurd You can simply check that the solutions are like this by writing $\prod_{i=1}^4(X-a_i)$, where $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are the four roots I suggested, and develop it.

Comment: with $\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}$ it works similarly with $\frac{1}{2}(\pm \sqrt{6}\pm \sqrt{2}i)$

Comment: From this, I get the system of equations 
$$
\begin{cases}
-s_1 = -a_1-a_2-a_3-a_4 = 0, \\
s_2 = a_1a_2 + a_1a_3 + a_1a_4 + a_2a_3 + a_2a_4 + a_3a_4 = 2, \\
-s_3 = -a_1a_2a_3 - a_1a_2a_4 - a_2a_3a_4 = 0, \\
s_4 = a_1a_2a_3a_4 = 4. 
\end{cases}
$$
I still don't see how to extract the formulas for the roots from this, maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction and overlooking the easy solution?

Comment: I can see the roots you suggested are indeed correct, but I wonder what is the method for finding them?

Comment: Btw, the polynomial that I am working with in this case is $f = X^4 -2X^2+4$.