# Compute the Galois group of $p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

> Compute the Galois group of the following polynomial:
>   $$p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

**Step 1:** Calculate cubic resolvent

**Step 2:** Calculate the discrimimant $\gamma$ of the cubic resolvent

**Step 3:** If $\gamma$ is a square then the Galois group is $A_4$, else $S_4$

Is this correct for all $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$?

How do we know if the Galois group is, for example, $\mathbb{Z_4}$?

Comment: As you recognize, there are other possibilities than just $S_4$ and $A_4$, so your Step 3 must be wrong. For examples, we have $f=X^4-4X^2-2$ and $g=X^4+X^3-6X^2-X+1$. Both of them give normal extensions with Galois group $Z_4$. You can check irreducibility of $g$ by calculating $g(X+4)$.

Comment: Thanks. What further step can we take to distinguish $\mathbb{Z}_4$ from $S_4$ and $A_4$?

Comment: And $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ is another abelian possibility I believe..

Comment: Sorry, this is not my game at all; all I would do is thrash around inefficiently till I found the automorphisms. There must be algorithms, but I don’t know them.

Comment: Another possibility if the dihedral group $D_8$, which is the Galois group of $x^4-2$, for example. There is a discussion of algorithms here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22923