# About the Galois group of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4+ax^2+b$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to prove:

> Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^4+ax^2+b$, whose roots are denoted by $\pm\alpha,\ \pm\beta$. Prove that $Gal(K/\mathbb Q)\cong V_4$ if and only if $\alpha\beta\in\mathbb Q$.

My question is: if we let
$$\sigma:\alpha\mapsto-\alpha,\ \beta\mapsto\beta$$
$$\tau:\alpha\mapsto\alpha,\ \beta\mapsto-\beta$$
Then if both are well-defined automorphisms of $K$, the group
$$\{1,\sigma,\tau,\sigma\tau\}$$
is isomorphic to $V_4$. However, $\sigma,\tau$ do not fix $\alpha\beta$, which means that this group must not be $Gal(K/\mathbb Q)$ (otherwise $\alpha\beta\notin\mathbb Q$, contradictory to what I am trying to prove) What is the reason?

p.s. I am aware that there questions asking about the same proposition. But they don't mention the problem that I am having here.

Comment: It seems to me that this is covered in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649466/galois-group-of-a-biquadratic-quartic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing the Galois group of $x^4+ax^2+b \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204709/computing-the-galois-group-of-x4ax2b-in-mathbbqx)

Comment: @ArnaudD. I don't see directly how. Is it possible that transitivity is the problem with the group that I constructed here?

Comment: Yes. Basically, you're not looking at the correct automorphisms of $K$, because you don't have anything that takes $\alpha$ to $\pm\beta$. (I'm assuming your quartic polynomial is irreducible.)

Comment: also $\alpha\beta=\sqrt{b}$ if that helps

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks! Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your roots have two different values of $\alpha\beta$, depending the signs you choose.  Call these possible values $+\gamma,-\gamma$.  You thus have a set of two products $\{+\gamma,-\gamma\}$.

When you apply $\sigma$ or $\tau$, then true, you do not map either of the individual elements $+\gamma,-\gamma$ into itself.  But you do map the *set* $\{+\gamma,-\gamma\}$ into itself.  Thus the set is invariant, and that is all you really need to identify a symmetry element.  The fact that you changed the order within the set does not change the set.